# In symfony 2 what would be the equivalent of zend's view helpers

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am looking for a way to have a site navigation menu which will be used primarily in a layout  file which is then extended in templates.

In zend I would create a view helper which would fetch the relevant items and render the links. I currently have the menu hard coded within a twig template which is extended by others (like a layout in zend). It doesn't feel like this is the best way to do it.

I'm effectively trying to split out the code into something separate as I am using the twig url helper to generate the links.

I have looked into twig functions but they seem to be primarily used for getting data rather than rendering html snippets that can be re-used. I have also thought about creating a service which gets the array of data with titles, routes etc but I think I would then have to use this in each action where the template needed the nav menu and it feels like too much duplication as symfony doesn't have controller init methods like in zend where you could do it once for all actions.

SO my question is, what's the recommended symfony2/twig way to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Zend but in Symfony you can easily have reusable twig snippets. All you need to do is write a specific controller method and its associated twig template then call it from wherever using the `render()` method. Example call from a twig template with one argument:

```
{{ render(controller("AcmeCategoryBundle:Category:menu", { 'position': 1 })) }}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. I have just added an extra action to my page controller to get the links and then pass them to the view which renders the menu.